# How to format reactive text output in R-Markdown?

Tags: shiny, r-markdown

In my Markdown file I use Shiny widgets to set some parameter. Add the end of the document some reactive text should be shown, depending on the choosen parameter, changing when a parameter is changed. This text should be formatted with linebreaks. Output format is HTML. The following minimal example shows my approach, the screenshot below the outcome. Unfortunatelly without linebreaks.

**How can I archieve linebreaks in reactive textoutput in R-Markdown?**

````
---
title: 'Minimal example'
runtime: shiny
output: 
  html_document

---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(shiny)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F)
```


```{r}
selectInput("input1", label = "Input1",
              choices = 1:5, selected = 1)

selectInput("input2", label = "Input2",
              choices = 1:5, selected = 1)

```

```{r}
### Generate Parameter for report
renderText({
        HTML(paste('Input1:', input$input1, '<br> Input2:', input$input2))
})

renderText({
        paste('Input1:', input$input1, ' \\n Input2:', input$input2)
})

renderText({
        paste('Input1:', input$input1, '  \n Input2:', input$input2)
})

renderText({
        cat(paste('Input1:', input$input1, '  \n Input2:', input$input2))
})
```
````

[image: HTML Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `renderUI` in combination with `HTML()` instead:

```
renderUI({
        HTML(paste('Input1:', input$input1, '<br> Input2:', input$input2))
})
```

Comment: Thank you. Are you aware of a way to have sequences like '\n' considered?